# Google Maps Flutter with Getx can not completely clear

Tags: flutter

I'm using Google Maps Flutter and GetX as my state manager. I have implemented markers and clustering using Fluster. However, when I refresh the markers (remove and recreate them), I noticed that one of the markers/clusters is not being deleted from the UI. Can someone please help me understand what might be causing this issue?

Here's a summary of my implementation:

1. I'm using Google Maps Flutter plugin to display the map.
2. I'm managing the state using GetX for reactive updates.
3. I'm using Fluster library to cluster the markers on the map.

The problem occurs when I try to refresh the markers by removing them from the map and recreating them based on updated data. Despite removing all the markers and clusters from the map, one of the markers/clusters remains visible.

I have already checked that I'm properly clearing the markers and clusters before recreating them. I suspect there might be some caching or synchronization issue that I'm not aware of.

There is my code:

```
class AssetDetailScreen extends GetView<AssetDetailController> {
  const AssetDetailScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    context.theme;
    return Obx(() {
      return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          controller.closePage();

          return false;
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          key: controller.scaffoldKey,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(controller.name.value),
            leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                controller.closePage();
              },
              icon: const BackButtonIcon(),
            ),
            actions: [
              Visibility(
                visible:
                    (GetStorage('Session').read<bool>('useHistory') ?? false) &&
                        !controller.isSelectDate.value,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () async {
                    await controller.goToHistory();
                  },
                  child: const SizedBox(
                    width: 50,
                    child: Icon(Icons.date_range),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () async {
                  if (controller.isSelectDate.value) {
                    await controller.exitHistory();
                  } else {
                    showLoading(false);
                    controller.completeClear();
                    await controller.getData();
                    controller.update();
                    Get.until((_) => Get.isDialogOpen != true);
                  }
                },
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 50,
                  child: Icon(controller.isSelectDate.value
                      ? Icons.close
                      : CupertinoIcons.arrow_2_circlepath),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Obx(() {
                return Animarker(
                  mapId: controller.controller.future.then((value) => value.mapId),
                  markers: Set<Marker>.of(controller.markers),
                  zoom: controller.zoom.value,
                  shouldAnimateCamera: false,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 900),
                  useRotation: false,
                  child: GoogleMap(
                    minMaxZoomPreference: const MinMaxZoomPreference(0, 24),
                    initialCameraPosition: indonesianLocation,
                    mapType: controller.mapType.value,
                    onMapCreated: (c) async {
                      showLoading(false);
                      if (isDarkMode) {
                        await c.setMapStyle(controller.themeString);
                      }

                      if (!controller.controller.isCompleted) {
                        controller.controller.complete(c);
                      }

                      await controller.initMap();
                      await controller.getData();
                      Get.until((_) => Get.isDialogOpen != true);
                    },
                    onCameraIdle: () async {
                      controller.createCluster();
                      controller.infoWindowController.onCameraIdle();
                      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300));
                      controller.canClose = true;
                    },
                    onCameraMove: (q) async {
                      controller.canClose = false;
                      controller.infoWindowController.onCameraMove();
                    },
                    onTap: (_) {
                      controller.infoWindowController.hideInfoWindow();
                    },
                    mapToolbarEnabled: false,
                    myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                    trafficEnabled: controller.mapTraffic.value,
                    zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                    // markers: Set<Marker>.of(controller.markers),
                    polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(controller.polyLines),
                    compassEnabled: false,
                    myLocationEnabled: false,
                    zoomGesturesEnabled: !controller.playing.value,
                    rotateGesturesEnabled: !controller.playing.value,
                    scrollGesturesEnabled: !controller.playing.value,
                    tiltGesturesEnabled: !controller.playing.value,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: controller.detailShowed.value
                            ? controller.padding.value
                            : 0),
                  ),
                );
              }),
              Visibility(
                visible: controller.isSelectDate.value,
                child: Positioned(
                  top: 16,
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                      await controller.selectDate();
                    },
                    child: Material(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      elevation: 10,
                      color: context.theme.colorScheme.background,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 8,
                          horizontal: 16,
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            const Icon(
                              Icons.date_range,
                              color: accentColor,
                            ),
                            mediumSpace,
                            Text(controller.selectedDate.isNotEmpty
                                ? Jiffy.parseFromDateTime(controller.selectedDate[0])
                                    .format(pattern: 'dd/MM/yyyy')
                                : 'Choose Date')
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 16,
                right: 16,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () async {
                        await controller.showAssetBound();
                      },
                      child: Material(
                        elevation: 10,
                        color: Get.context?.theme.colorScheme.background,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          side: BorderSide(
                            width: 0.2,
                            color: context.theme.colorScheme.mapButtonBorder,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.my_location,
                              color: context.theme.colorScheme.iconOnPrimary,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    largeSpace,
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        controller.openSetting();
                      },
                      child: Material(
                        elevation: 10,
                        color: Get.context?.theme.colorScheme.background,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          side: BorderSide(
                            width: 0.2,
                            color: context.theme.colorScheme.mapButtonBorder,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Icon(
                              CupertinoIcons.settings,
                              color: context.theme.colorScheme.iconOnPrimary,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: Get.mediaQuery.padding.bottom == 0
                    ? 16
                    : Get.mediaQuery.padding.bottom,
                right: 16,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    controller.showDetail();
                  },
                  child: Material(
                    elevation: 10,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      side: BorderSide(
                        width: 0.2,
                        color: context.theme.colorScheme.mapButtonBorder,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                    ),
                    color: Get.context?.theme.colorScheme.background,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_upward,
                          color: context.theme.colorScheme.iconOnPrimary,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

and I clear with:

```
markers.removeWhere((q) => q.markerId.value != 'AssetMarker');
```

then

```
update();
```

but there is still one or more marker that not removed (besides with markerId 'AssetMarker')

Any suggestions or insights on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I try to change my code using stateful widget and using setState for update, that issue still exist, there is some marker not removed

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was calling the method to recreate markers too frequently, causing Google Maps to cache unnecessarily. After removing the line that calls the method when the page is initially opened, my issue no longer occurs.